# Tracing the outline of an image using drop shadow css3 filter. Works perfectley in Firefox but no other browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I referenced this source and a number of others when trying to create a drop shadow outline of an image on my website. It traces the outline of the image perfectly in Firefox, but doesn't work in Chrome, Safari, Opera, etc.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

I found this code, which works exactly as I hoped it would in Firefox. The shadow doesn't just create a block shadow behind the image, it actually shows the inner and outer outlines of the shadow as they trace the shape.

```
header img:hover {
        filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #808080);
}
```

I don't have an example of this working except if you hover over the logo in the upper left corner of my website, (view it in Firefox) seanquinndesign.com

What are the options, if any, of making this code compatible with all browsers?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r3xssjo8/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `webkit` and `o` prefix

1. for Chrome:

   ```
   -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #808080);
   ```
2. for Opera:

   ```
   -o-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #808080);
   ```